# Too many redirects PHP MVC

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

```
class Core {

protected $currentController = '';
protected $currentMethod = '';
protected $params = [];

public function __construct() {

    $url = $this->getUrl();

    $pages = [
        "" => ["controller" => "Pages", "method" => "index"],
        "profile" => ["controller" => "Pages", "method" => "profile"],
        "help" => ["controller" => "Pages", "method" => "help"],
        "signin" => ["controller" => "Pages", "method" => "signin"]
    ];

    // cant access controller
    $noaccess = ["pages"];


    if (in_array($url[0], $noaccess)) {
        redirect("/");
    }


    if (isLoggedIn()) {
        if (!in_array($url[0], $noaccess)) {
            if (!array_key_exists($url[0], $pages)) {
                if (file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]) . '.php')) {
                    // If exists, set as controller
                    $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
                    $this->currentMethod = "index";
                    // Unset 0 Index
                    unset($url[0]);
                } else {
                    // 404
                    $this->currentController = "Pages";
                    $this->currentMethod = "error404";
                    unset($url[0]);
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($pages as $page => $options) {
                    if ($url[0] == $page) {
                        $this->currentController = $options['controller'];
                        $this->currentMethod = $options['method'];
                        //unset($url[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        redirect("signin");
    }


    // Require the controller
    require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php';

    // Instantiate controller class
    $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

    // Check for second part of url
    if (isset($url[1])) {
        // Check to see if method exists in controller
        if (method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])) {
            $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
            // Unset 1 index
            unset($url[1]);
        }
    }

    // Get params
    $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
    // Call a callback with array of params
    call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);
}

public function getUrl() {
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        return $url;
    }
}
```

}

I'm learning how to make my own MVC framework for PHP. I'm trying to redirect the user in the core class that instantiates a controller based on the url.

`example.com/posts/` will instantiate the Post Controller.

I want to redirect them to `/signin/` if they're not logged in. No page will be accessible if the user isn't signed in.

I have a basic function called `isLoggedIn()` which checks for a `$_SESSION` variable. I'm able to test if it works with a `die()` command.

Everything works, but I get an error saying too many redirects. My redirect regarding the `$noaccess` works without this issue, but I can't get the loggedIn one to work. I'm not sure why it's having this issue.

Comment: _No page will be accessible if the user isn't signed in._ Well, remember that the login page must be accessible for everyone but logged in users. So the logic changes there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that. At this point no one will be signed in since I have to build it out. I'm trying to force the /signin/ page first.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. All I'm saying is that if this Core class is called on every page, then the sign in page will redirect to itself all the time, causing the multiple redirections. That's just my theory, though. I personally use methods in a Session class to do this, but always outside the Session's constructor. Maybe that will help. (They are obviously not used within the class)

Comment: ah, you were right! I had to put a condition to ignore the redirect when the url was /signin/. thank you :). i cant upvote because of my low rep

Comment: It’s ok, I’ll add the answer and you can later accept it. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every page creates a new Core object, including the sign in page, then whenever you try to sign in (access the sign in page), it will keep redirecting to itself in a never-ending loop.

Adding a condition or simply not checking for login data in the constructor should do the trick. There are many ways to do it, but that’s the general idea.

In the end, all pages run the same logic except the login page, which reverses it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zeke: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3654197/zeke

Whenever I was redirecting to /signin/, that was also trying to redirect which caused a loop.

I put a condition to only redirect if the the url wasn't /signin/

```
  if ( !isLoggedIn()) {
    if ($url[0] == "signin") {
      $this->currentController = "Pages";
      $this->currentMethod = "signin";
    } else {
      redirect('signin');

    }
    unset($url[0]);
  }
```